# Help with sequence $1\cdot n + 2(n-1) + \ldots + (n-1)2 + n\cdot 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can anyone please provide a simplified formula for the sum of the sequence
\begin{equation*}
s(n) = 1\cdot n + 2(n-1) + \ldots + (n-1)2 + n\cdot1
\end{equation*}
where $n$ is an integer greater than $0$?

for instance, $s(1)=1,~ s(2)=4,~ s(3)=10,~ s(7)=84$ (I believe)
but what is, say, $s(15)$?  (without resorting to a computer)

Thanks! :)

Comment: Note that $s(1)=1$. The sequence is [A000292](http://oeis.org/A000292) in the OEIS.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, of course.  I wrote it as 1 initially then edited it incorrectly.  Will do so again!  Many thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite your sum using sigma notation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(n-(i-1)) $$
Then use basic formulas like:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$
to simplify your expression.

Comment: I was about to mention that your sum wasn't correct, then you fixed it ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's been twenty years or more since I've used sigma notation! :)

Comment: and I eventually get to n(n+1)(n+2)/6 - and 680 :)  Thankfully, vadim123's link agrees... :D

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} k(n+1-k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {k\choose 1}{n+1-k\choose 1}={k+n+1-k+1\choose 1+1+1}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&1\cdot n + 2\cdot (n-1) + 3\cdot (n-3)+\cdots 
+ (n-1)\cdot 2 + n\cdot1\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n r(n+1-r)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n+1-r}r\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^{n+1-j}r\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^j {r\choose 1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n {j+1\choose 2}\\
&={n+2 \choose 3}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Write as:

$\begin{align*}
   S_{n + 1}
     &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n + 1} k (n + 1 - k)
\end{align*}$

You see this is a convolution, the coefficients of the sum:

$\begin{align*}
   S(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} S_n z^n \\
     &= \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} k z^k \right)^2 \\
     &= \frac{z^2}{(1 - z)^4}
\end{align*}$

Using the generalized binomial theorem, you get the coefficients as:

$\begin{align*}
   S_{n + 1}
     &= [z^{n + 1}] S(z) \\
     &= [z^{n - 1}] (1 - z)^{-4} \\
     &= (-1)^{n - 1} \binom{-4}{n - 1} \\
     &= \binom{n - 1 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} \\
     &= \frac{n (n + 1) (n + 2)}{6}
\end{align*}$